# Is my program calculating wrong?

Tags: c#

So in my C# class, I was asked to;

> Write a program that computes the amount of money the computer club will receive from proceeds of their granola bar sales project. Allow the user to enter the number of cases sold and the sale price per bar.Each case contains 12 bars; each case is purchased at $5.00 per case from a local vendor.The club is required to give the student government association 10% of their earnings. Display their proceeds formatted with currency. Write appropriate methods for your solution.

I wrote the program but I am pretty sure the math is not adding up (unless I am screwing up the calculations that I am plugging into my calculator.
Here is my code.

```
using System;

namespace GranolaBars
{
    class Granola
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Give user info on program
            Console.WriteLine("The Computer Club buys the cases at $5.00 a case");
            Console.WriteLine("The studdent government gets 10% of profit");
            Console.WriteLine("Total made from sell is number of cases sold minus 10%");

            // Declare the variables
            int casesSold;
            decimal pricePerBar;
            decimal profit;
            decimal proceeds;
            decimal finalOutCome;

            // Set the variables values
            casesSold = GetCasesSold();
            pricePerBar = GetPricePerCase();
            profit = GetProfit(casesSold, pricePerBar);
            proceeds = GetProceeds(profit);
            finalOutCome = GetFinalOutCome(proceeds, profit);

            // The output from the program 
            Console.WriteLine("The amount cases of sold was: {0} ", casesSold);
            Console.WriteLine("The price per bar was {0:C}: ", pricePerBar);
            Console.WriteLine("The gross profit is: {0:C}: ", profit);
            Console.WriteLine("The student government fees are: {0:C} ", proceeds);
            Console.WriteLine("The income minus the student government fees is: {0:C} ", finalOutCome);

            Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static int GetCasesSold()
    // Method that gets the total number of cases sold
    {
        int CSold;
        Console.Write("Enter the number of cases sold: ");
        CSold = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return CSold;
    }
    public static decimal GetPricePerCase()
    // Method that gets the price per case of garnola bars
    {
        decimal PerBar;
        Console.Write("Enter the price per bar: ");
        PerBar = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return PerBar;
    }
    public static decimal GetProfit(int CasesSold, decimal PricePerBar)
    // Method to get the Profit
    {
        decimal PriceofCase = 5.00M;
        decimal Earnings;
        Earnings = ((PricePerBar * 12) - PriceofCase);
        return Earnings;
    }
    public static decimal GetProceeds(decimal Profit)
    // Method to get the Proceeds
    {
        decimal StudentGovFunds = .10M;
        return (Profit * StudentGovFunds);
    }
    public static decimal GetFinalOutCome(decimal Proceeds, decimal Profit)
    // Method to calculate the final total made from selling granola pars
    {
        return (Profit - Proceeds);
    }
}
```

Is my program calculating correctly or am I missing what would make it calculate correctly?

Comment: Use a paper and pencil.  Figure out the correct answer for a set of values.  Run the app, using those values.  If they match, it is correct.  Repeat for a range of numbers.  If not, use the [step debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx).  This isnt really a problem for us to solve.

Comment: So basically the `student government association` is running a protection racket

Comment: Also, please read [ask] and take the [tour].  The score on your past contributions is poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem

I mean you need to times how many cases are sold at least at some point

```
 public static decimal GetProfit(int CasesSold, decimal PricePerBar)
 // Method to get the Profit
 {
    return (((PricePerBar * 12) - PriceofCase) * CasesSold); 
 }
```

output

```
The Computer Club buys the cases at $5.00 a case
The studdent government gets 10% of profit
Total made from sell is number of cases sold minus 10%
Enter the number of cases sold: 2
Enter the price per bar: 10
The amount cases of sold was: 2
The price per bar was $10.00:
The gross profit is: $230.00:
The student government fees are: $23.00
The income minus the student government fees is: $207.00
```